# Can't install libgnokii

Tags: installation, libraries, fedora-12, dependencies

I am trying to install [Gnocky](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnocky/) on Fedora and as I was installing it, I got a message about dependencies.  I need to install libgnokii.so.2 and libbluetooth.  I tried searching for these files on the Internet but was not able to find one.

How do I install Gnocky on my Fedora 12?

Answer (score 0):

libbluetooth is in the `bluez-libs` package, but libgnokii.so.2 is ancient. The `gnokii` package in Fedora 12 provides libgnokii.so.5. Install the `gnokii-devel` and `bluez-libs-devel` packages and rebuild gnocky from source.

```
yum whatprovides libgnokii.so.* libbluetooth.so.*
yum whatprovides \*/libgnokii.so \*/libbluetooth.so
```